# UPDATED : flutter sign in with realtime database firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i have a problem with my project. i want to sign in with realtime data firebase using id and password. most of tutorial I found using authentication (email and pass) and I'm new to flutter. Please help me T.T

**update** : I can sign in using username and pass and it only print the values in debug console. i want to make the data display in user profile screen but I'm not done yet with the screen. i appreciate all the comments below and if you guys wants comments regarding my updated code please do that. it really helps me doing my projects. i will update here if i have any problem regarding my userprofie.

login

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:staffprofile.dart';
import 'signup.dart';

class StaffLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  StaffLogin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StaffLoginState createState() => _StaffLoginState();
}

class _StaffLoginState extends State<StaffLogin> {
  final dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Staff");
  void loginfb(String userID, String password) async {
    dataRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(userID).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> StaffProfile()),);
        print(values["name"]);
        print(values["email"]);
        print(values["contact no"]);
      });
    });
  }

  var username = TextEditingController();
  var password = TextEditingController();
  final signin_formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: new Color(0xffD7BDE2),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [new Color(0xffA3E4D7), new Color(0xffC39BD3)],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),

        child: Form(
          key: signin_formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0)),
              Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/email.png'),
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
              ),
              Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0)),
              Text(
                "SMART MAILBOX",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),

              //USERNAME FORMFIELD
              Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (staffuser) {
                  if (staffuser == null || staffuser.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your username';
                  }
                },
                controller: username,
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
                  labelText: 'Staff ID',
                ),
                onChanged: (val) {},
              ),

              //PASSWORD FORMFIELD
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (pass) {
                  if (pass == null || pass.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your password';
                  }
                },
                controller: password,
                obscureText: true,
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.vpn_key,
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (val) {},
              ),
              // ignore: unnecessary_new
              new Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                  child: new ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      'Sign In',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (signin_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        loginfb(username.text, password.text);
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.purple),
                  )),
              new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Do not have an account?',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign Up',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
                        );
                      },
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.purple,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my realtime data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr85D.png)

(ignore this-dvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-)

Comment: You can check Peter's wonderful article regarding [How To Use Firebase Authentication In Flutter](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-flutter-50e8b81cb29f).

Comment: Can you explain the specific issue you are having with authentication? Are you currently getting an error?

Comment: There is no built-in provider in Firebase for username+password authentication. If you want that, you can build a custom provider like shown here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/username-password-auth This is quite non-trivial though, so I recommend starting with the built-in providers, and for example then associating a unique user name with each user in your database as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295265/unique-username-in-firebase-with-flutter.

Comment: thank you alex for the suggestion but it using authentication (email and password) and i found similar problem with mine and for now i can sign in with username and pass but it only print the values in the debug console because I'm not done yet with my user profile.. if my user profile's done i want to make my screen like this login() => userProfile(). means, i want to display my user info in userproflle screen